# How to associate a facebook comment box with a post in a div on my website?

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I understand this is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
which generates javascript and html code.
heres a pick of what i mean
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/63111556/ubuntu.png

On my website I am trying to create a blog so User Posts a comment 
Now there will be different posts from users
how can i make a comment box related to the specific posts on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `data-href` on the div for each usage. you can set it to an element id or post number to make them all different:

```
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://yourwebsite.com/#postIDorNumber" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://yourwebsite.com/#postIDorNumber2" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://yourwebsite.com/#postIDorNumber3" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

Should be fairly easy to implement into a blog to dynamically add the post id to the `data-href`

Comment: so based on the dropbox link you i would want element id

Comment: so  data-href="http://yourwebsite.com/#element id"???

Comment: each comment has to have a unique `data-href`.. you can do any combination of whatever you like really. as long as it gets you to the relevant page `data-href='http://www.yoursite.com/blog/pageID.html#elementID-fb-comments-unique-whatever`.  if the comments are only going to be on the blog entry page and one comment box per page, i would stick with the post url: `data-href="http://www.yoursite/blog-post-4.html"`

Comment: this is my workaround So i can just have a click listener that i list all the posts for a day , then if you click on it , it will take you to another page and boom now i have a different url with the post they clicked on

Comment: awesome! as long as it works like you are expecting, that's a good thing. keep developing

Answer (score 0):

The code that the Facebook page generates is this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

I'd reccomend giving each of your posts a seperate URL representation:
/blog/food/my-sandwich
/blog/food/my-chicken-fritter

And simply changing the `data-href` parameter when you render the list of posts.

For example:

```
<?php
 foreach($posts as $post) {
  echo '<div class="post">';
  echo '<div class="post-title">' . $post->title . '</div>';
  echo '<div class="post-content">' . $post->content . '</div>';
  echo '<div class="post-comments"><div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://yoursite.com/blog/' . $post->url . '" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div></div>';
  echo '</div>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long i put a link up with a picture? how would I make a link for each "post"? all the posts will be one page

Comment: Just explained that to you mate? It's a case of making a different URL to put in the `data-href` parameter of the div that will permanently represent the post.

Comment: I see I wanted more than one post on a page

Comment: So i can just have a click listener that i list all the posts for a day , then if you click on it , it will take you to another page and boom now i have a different url with the post they clicked on